# End user authentication in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

in the last few days I have looked into Google Cloud Storage Buckets. **I would like to know how to authenticate and authorize users when accessing data, preferably without the use of a backend.**

Context: I have an app with the following requirements: Authenticated end users should be able to upload data to a (or their) bucket, with the default read access being scope to the user. At any point, the owner of the bucket should allow the bucket contents to be available to the public (publish bucket contents, read only).

End users are currently being authenticated with JWTs on the browser.

I have looked at the different ways of controlling access to Storage Buckets.

To my understanding:

- IAM is unsuitable as it is meant for Google Accounts and should be used within the company, not to authenticate end users (clients)
- ACLs are seemingly not recommended and are described as a legacy way meant for interoperability with S3
- Signed URLs are "ok" for uploads, but I would rather have an actually authenticated way of uploading.

What's totally unclear to me: what access control method can be used to authenticate my end users (pref. with JWTs) especially for reading data?

This seems like an issue everyone should face, but I can't seem to find good info? On a side note: I am aware that Firebase exists for this reason, I just want to know how to tackle this on GCP.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other solution than signed URL and a backend (I know that breaks your requirement) that check the authentication and generate that signedURL (on only the relevant/authorized files)

Comment: So I understand correctly that signed URL with the correctly configured (short TTL) are the way to go? But what if someone were to get access to this link? Should I resort to using firebase and connect my buckets through that instead?

Comment: Your authenticated user perform a request to your backend. The backend checks the authentication validity, and answer back SignerURL(s) of the files related to the user.  You have to keep a link between the user and the files (or the buckets) that belong to them. In firestore, it's perfect (and you can perform a search in that index).

Answer (score 0):

When implementing this purely in GCP, you'll typically end up implementing your own auth solution for your clients, and then your own authorization model in your server-side code.

If you want to not implement this yourself, using Firebase for your Cloud Storage access would be the way to go. This implements client-side authentication and server-side security rules to control access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When going the Firebase route, I assume that it is wiser to use the "one bucket for many customers" method instead of "one bucket per customer?

Comment: Both are possible, as you can specify the bucket when initializing the SDK. But if you control access through Firebase security rules, the need for having a bucket per customer often disappears.

Comment: After almost a year has passed, I have just stumbled upon my own question. Since I still haven't found solid alternatives, could you elaborate on what the "industry" standard way of authorizing access to buckets/objects is? Is a reverse proxy that accesses a private bucket on behalf of the user (after checking authorization) and then streaming the response back to the user the way to go? I can't seem to find any resources on this! Seems like every second SaaS would need to securely store user data in buckets yet it's so hard to do?